# Errors with core data after upgrading to Xcode 8 and converting to Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I am getting following errors

[image]

after I upgraded my Xcode to Xcode 8 and converted syntax to swift 3. Does that mean that AppDelegate does not support those functions anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSFetchRequest` and `NSFetchedResultsController` are now generic classes in Swift 3. You'll need to declare your fetch request and results controller with the types they are fetching. Something like this:

`var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<Item> = NSFetchedResultsController()`

and

```
func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Item> {


    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")
    ...
}
```